# Node date retrieved from postrgresql is being converted to an undesired format

Tags: javascript, node.js, date

I have a pg select

```
db.query("SELECT * from users where id ="+userId).then(data => {
   console.log(data[0].birth_date)
})
```

Which returns

```
1997-08-11T22:00:00.000Z
```

I have prepared a function to parse the data

```
function filterDate(date) {
console.log("inside")
console.log(date)
var stringDate = date.toString();
var result = stringDate.match(/(?:(?!T).)*/)
console.log(result)
console.log("inside")
return result[0];
```

}

Which should return `1997-98-11` Problem is that , whenever the .toString() happens inside filterDate, it preformats the date to an invalid string `'Tue Aug 12 1997 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (GMT+02:00)',`  . I was handling it in the client side, so I was directly doing it after a res.send, and it was working fine. But now if i date.toString() in the server side it reformats it to a weird format. How do I avoid it and mantain the first format?

Comment: If `date.toString()` implies that DB is not returning a string but (possibly) a `Date` object (I don't know, I'm not familiar with your toolset) perhaps all you have is a *how to format dates in JavaScript* question. If unsure, what do you get when you run `console.log(typeof data[0].birth_date)`?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález fixed it with ```console.log(moment(date).format('YYYY-MM-DD'))``` thanks to your idea

Comment: I'm glad you fixed it but that doesn't have anything to do with anything I said in my comment :)

Comment: @mouchin777 If possible add your answer here. So that in future someone might get help from this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using moment npm

```
  function filterDate(date) {
    var stringDate = moment(date).format('YYYY-MM-DD').toString();
    var result = stringDate.match(/(?:(?!T).)*/)
    return result[0];
  }
```

And then

```
deathDate = moment(filterDate(birth_date)).add(yearsToLive, 'years')
```

Will assign the proper format as YYYY-MM-DD